# All data disappears from graph when rightmost rendered data goes off screen

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

At the moment it is happening in combined chart, after I zoom into the chart and start moving to left side, as soon as the rightmost rendered shape(scatter, bar, line, whichever) goes off chart screen all other rendered shapes in current chart go invisible. Anyone know what might be the problem?